# Laravel access value from others object

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have 3 tables :-

available_offers
- id 
- date 
- time 
- from 
- to 
- user_id

requested_offer
- id 
- user_id 
- available_offersID

user
- id 
- name 
- username 
- password 
- email

Here my routes_bookedController

```
class routes_bookedController extends Controller
{
public function create() 
{
    $user = available_offers::with('user')->get();
    $booked = requested_routes::with('available_offers', 'user')
            ->where('user_id', Auth::id())
            ->get();

    return $booked;

    return view ('routes_booked.show', compact('booked'));
   }
}
```

Here the result from show.blade.php from routes_bookedController

```
[
   {
      "id": 3,
      "user_id": 4,
      "available_offersID": 3,
      "created_at": null,
      "updated_at": null,
      "available_offers": {
           "id": 3,
           "date": "2017-08-08",
           "time": "14:11:30",
           "from": "Sabah",
           "to": "Sarawak",
           "user_id": 2,
           "isBooked": 1,
           "created_at": null,
           "updated_at": null
   },
      "user": {
           "id": 4,
           "name": "admin",
           "username": "user1",
           "email": "user1@example.com",
           "created_at": "2017-08-08 06:15:49",
           "updated_at": "2017-08-08 06:15:49"
      }
   }
 ]
```

Is that possible to grab name from available_offers->user->name ?

This is my model :-

1. requested_routes

   ```
   class requested_routes extends Model
   {
   public function available_offers()
   {
       return $this->belongsTo(available_offers::class, 'available_offersID');
   }

   public function user()
   {
       return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
   }
   }
   ```
2. available_offers

   ```
   class available_offers extends Model
   {
   public function user()
   {
       return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
   }

   public function requested_routes() 
   {
       return $this->hasMany(requested_routes::class);
    }
    }
   ```
3. User

   ```
   public function available_offers() 
   {
      return $this->hasMany(available_offers::class);
   }

   public function requested_routes()
   {
      return $this->hasMany(requested_routes::class);
   }
   ```

Comment: Yes, that should work just fine.

Comment: it should work because when you dded you can see that the user object has the property name which equals to admin so it should output admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eager load sub model

```
$booked = requested_routes::with('available_offers', 'available_offers.user', 'user')
         ->where('user_id', Auth::id())
         ->get();
```

Ensure you add **available_offers.user** as one of the with clauses.